# ggplot: Scale up text labels and when scaling up size of plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, png

When generating plots, it is often necessary to make these plots larger when exporting. This can be done as follows:

```
png(filename = "plot_name.png", width=1000, height = 800)
print(plot)
dev.off()
```

Unfortunatley, the elements of the plot are NOT scaled up along with it's overall size. This means that I end up adding a bunch of elements to theme(), as follows.

```
theme(
  legend.position = "bottom",
  legend.title = element_text(size=20),
  plot.title = element_text(size = 30),
  axis.title = element_text(size=20),
  axis.text = element_text(size=15),
  legend.text = element_text(size=15)
 )
```

Is there are way to scale up all of the elements of the plot along with its overall size?

Answer (score 9):

You can set a `base_size` for any given theme to scale up all text proportionately. For example, `theme_grey(base_size=15)` or `theme_bw(base_size=20)`, etc. If you have a ggplot called `p1`, just do `p1 + theme_bw(base_size=20)`.

You can also do this for all future plots in an R session by running, e.g., `theme_set(theme_bw(base_size=20))`.

Even after setting `base_size`, you might still want to tweak a few things. To reduce typing, you can create a list of plot elements once and then reuse it. For example:

```
my_thm = list(theme(legend.position = "bottom",
                    legend.title = element_text(size=20),
                    plot.title = element_text(size = 30),
                    axis.title = element_text(size=20),
                    axis.text = element_text(size=15),
                    legend.text = element_text(size=15)),
              scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,100)),
              scale_colour_manual(values=hcl(c(15,195),100,65)))
```

Then, when you create a new plot, just add `+ my_thm` on the end to add all of the plot elements in `my_thm`. If you're going to use both a general theme (like `theme_bw()`) along with additional `theme` elements, make sure to add any additional `theme` elements *after* `theme_bw()`, as `theme_bw()` and other general themes will override any preceding `theme` elements.

Comment: `base_size` let's you scale the text elements in the theme consistently but it doesn't maintain the proportion with respect to the viewport. In the context of a bigger image e.g. `png(filename = "plot_name.png", width=2000, height = 1600)` the text will be half the size.